# Is it natural that cops attack another cop?

Tags: need-for-speed-rivals

I am playing the latest version of Need For Speed Rivals on my PS4.
I have been playing offline as a cop and was chasing down a racer, then another cop joined in and hit me, while he was supposed to help me.

Is this common behaviour? Or is it simply a bug? Or should I change my settings somewhere?

When I use Shockwave on racers, the cops around me get affected too - maybe this makes them angry?